# how to check the special chars like ( >, < ,-, 0-9) exists in string using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to check only string contains  ( >, <, -, 0-9) using preg_match, If exists return true. Here is my trial :

```
   $page_num  ="25-100"; or $page_num = ">300";
  if (preg_match('/[0-9]+<+>/', $page_num))
  {
   return true;
  }
```

Comment: your regex is executing as "one or more digits, followed by one or more `<`, followed by a single `>`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct regex :

```
if (preg_match('/[><\-0-9]/', $page_num))
```

If you want to check if all characters are one of these (`^` and `$` force the string to contain only these characters from the start of the string untill the end) :

```
if (preg_match('/^[><\-0-9]+$/', $page_num))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
^[0-9-<>]+$
```